# set php variable as x,y location of image in html

Tags: php, html, variables, loops

I am trying to set the x and y of an image in html to the value of a php variables so that the coordinate is in a loop so that the image is drawn 5 times in a row. If someone could figure out how to set left: to $x that would be great

```
<?php

for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
$counter = 0;
$x = 200;
echo '<img src="stat.png" height="300" width="150"style="position: absolute; top:
   10px; left: <?php echo $x; ?> px;"/>';
// above is where I am trying to use the php variable
$x += 200;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Two things: You weren't doing concatenation correctly for `$x`, and you redefined `$x = 200` at every iteration rather than to set up the original value. See below

```
<?php
$x = 200;

for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
$counter = 0;
echo '<img src="stat.png" height="300" width="150"style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left:'.$x.'px;"/>
';
// above is where I am trying to use the php variable
$x += 200;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already writing that in PHP, so you don't need to include php tags in your echo statement. Just echo the variable into it.

```
'left:' . $x . 'px;
```

Comment: OP is using single quotes which will not parse out variables. With single quotes, concatenation is the only option. Or OP can use doubles.

Answer (score 0):

You're redefining `$x` in each iteration of your loop. So `$x` will always be equal to 200 and the `$x += 200` has no effect.

Try this

```
<?php foreach (range(0, 4) as $ratio): 
    $x = $ratio * 200;
    ?>
    <img src="stat.png" height="300" width="150" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: <?php echo $x ?>px;"/>
<?php endforeach ?>
```